# Combine rows of varying length google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

[image]

How can I combine rows of varying length like above?

I want a function, that can combine rows 1-4 and end up with one row with all the values like row 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:C4); "where Col1 is not null"; 0))
```

Comment: I like this solution. Can it also be done so that i will be more dynamic and work with rows of any length? Like if I suddenly add a row of length 4?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald sure, you can change your A1:C4 to A1:Z or A1:1000. ofc to avoid circular error the formula always needs to stay out of the used range or best - on another sheet

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY()` function is best for this case. Alternatively you can use `FILTER()` formula like-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FLATTEN(A1:C4),FLATTEN(A1:C4)<>""))
```

[image]